# Task Scheduler for Python Scripts not Running

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I have some python tasks for work scheduled to run in the evening/early morning. The scripts work when I trigger them manually but not when my laptop is not in use, and I don’t turn it off. I also have a VPN connection script that connects every 30min (databases can only be queried when connected to VPN).

The scheduler settings are set to “run only when user is logged on”- this should still work regardless since I don’t log out and a colleague used the same settings prior to run the scripts? When I try to select “run whether user is logged on or not” I receive a pop up that requires me to have batch job rights which I don’t think can be enabled. The IT team at my firm told me there is a policy to automatically lock the computer when not in use. I tried adjusting power and sleep settings to never turn off/go to sleep and the screen to turn off on battery power after 10mins. How can I configure scheduler/other settings to run the jobs?

Comment: Which operating system? This isn't really a question about the python program, but how to schedule it. You may be better off asking on superuser.com.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: OS is Windows 10